# Destroy activity started from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I started my activity from `BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SipCallActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("destination_phone", phoneNumber);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

after a while activity is finished by pressing button:

```
Button endCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_btn_terminate_call);
endCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            endCall(); //SIP related stuff
            finish();
        }
    });
```

All is fine and dandy. But when I'm trying to open another activity from application by pressing icon from application list or from recent applications list via Home button I always get the activity I just closed - `SipCallActivity`. Why is that?

I want to close that activity and user should never see it again unless invoked from my `BroadcastReceiver`. How could I achieve that?

Comment: i guess you got your answer . set flag pragmatically, as mentioned by vikalp instead  of manifest. because you want this behavior in case of broadcast only, not always .

Comment: Well, that activity will be launched only from broadcast, so manifest param is perfect. Unless there's side effect I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add the flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS) to your launching intent, or use the following in the manifest to exclude the app from recents:

`<activity android:name="<your-activity"`[`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)`...`

Comment: Yes, that works. I used Manifest approach.
By the way is there a way to keep other activities in history?
I launched "Manual Activity" navigated away with home button. Activity from BroadcastListener is launched and finished - application from recent activities is missing.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to add flag to your intent which calls mainactivity

```
i.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

### OR

Inside your Mainfest File::

```
<activity android:name=".SipCallActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```